# Img appears in random place while having scaleX(0);

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

So I have a section in a page where I list some links that have a **preview image on the right**.

The architecture for each link I have is a logo on the left, a label for the link and an image to the right.
When I hover over each link, the image `scaleX` becomes `1` and then if I hover over the image, I can visit the desired link, by clicking a prompt.
For some reason, the last preview image of my links **appears randomly at the top left of my div** and I can't seem to find a reason. Firstly why is its `scaleX` not `0` and secondly, why does it appear so far out of its position.

I made a minimalistic demo so you can see.

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/demo-24v6jt?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A6%2C6)

My best guess is the **animation-timeline: scroll(root block);** property, cause it happens when I scroll down towards the `div`.

In case there is any relation, i use Chrome version: 120.0.6099.227
and i am on Windows 11 Home OS.

```js
function App() {
  const projectsData = [
    // ... (your existing projectsData array)
  ];

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(projectsData);

  const updateProjects = (updatedProjects) => {
    setProjects(updatedProjects);
  };

  const handleMouseEnter = (index) => {
    const updatedProjects = projects.map((project, i) => {
      if (i !== index) {
        return { ...project, opacity: 0.5 };
      } else {
        return { ...project, opacity: 1 };
      }
    });
    updateProjects(updatedProjects);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    const updatedProjects = projects.map((project) => ({
      ...project,
      opacity: 1,
    }));
    updateProjects(updatedProjects);
  };

  return (
    <section className="bottom-section">
      <div className="projects-container">
        <div className="bracket" style={{ marginLeft: "5%" }}>
          &lt;section id='projects'&gt;
        </div>
        <div className="projects">
          {projects.map((project, index) => (
            <div
              className="project"
              onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(index)}
              onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
              key={index}
            >
              <div className="label" style={{ opacity: project.opacity }}>
                {project.logo}
                <a id="name" href={project.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                  {project.name}
                </a>
              </div>
              <div
                className="img"
                style={{ background: `url(${project.img})`, backgroundSize: "contain" }}
              >
                <a id="visit" href={project.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                  Visit
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="bracket">&lt;/section&gt;</div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
:root {
  --color1: #f3fffe;
  --color2: #1c91ff;
  --color3: #00a39b;
  --color4: #171a20;
}

* {
  color: var(--color1);
}

section {
  margin-top: 25svh;
  background-color: #171a20;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85svh;
}

.top-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.projects-container .bracket:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  left: 55%;
  top: 5svh;
}

.projects {
  position: relative;
  animation: expand 0.5s forwards;
  animation-timeline: scroll(root block);
}

.project {
  height: 15svh;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 70vw;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color3);
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
}

.project .label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.project .label svg {
  fill: var(--color1);
  width: 3vw;
}

.project:hover .label {
  transform: translateX(10%);
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.project .label #name {
  font-family: "Asty";
  color: var(--color1);
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding-left: 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30vw;
}

.project .img {
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.project #visit {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color2);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.project:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.project:hover .img {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.project .img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.project .img:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project #visit:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems like it could be a browser bug, at least in Chrome.

Comment: yeah ,i guessed so to, but i cant understand the root problem, if its the animation , of the div itself

Comment: @DimitrisS What browser and OS are you using? I tried this in Safari and FIrefox and it looked fine. I tried it in Chrome and Brave, and when scrolling everything get's larger but the images are already showing at the top left corner. Are you seeing any of these things?

Comment: @Bjorn.B Yes, i used chrome also and i see the last image specifically in the top left corner

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix. When viewing your sandbox example, I could see all of the images stacking behind each other in the top left. An edit that I tested directly in the console was: `.project .img {overflow: hidden};`, or `.project { position: relative}`. I'm not 100% certain, but what appears to be happening is that while `background-image` is applied to `.project .img` along with `transform: scaleX(0)`, it's unaffected with the transform parameter. This looks like it then causes the background image to flow out of it's area and to the last parent with a set `position`, which is `.projects`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, i ve tried overvlow hidden in the img before, i just forgot to mention it, putting a position: relative in my .project div, didnt work either...

Comment: @DimitrisS Next thing I would try and do is take a video or make a gif of what your issue looks like on your system, and then put that in your question so we can see what is happening. It could even come down to the OS or version of chrome.

Comment: 120.0.6099.227 version of Chrome, Windows 11 Home OS and will definetaly post a gif showing the bug

Comment: for some reason i can't post a gif , so here's the link if you want to see it https://gifyu.com/image/SCKpf